# Not able to access 'this' in an 'each' within a Class.create

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have the following code snippet. It is confusing, because I can't seem to access 'this' within the each.

The used **JavaScript library is Prototype.**

```
MyClass = Class.create({

  initialize : function(options) {

    this.testmsg = 'Hi!';
    alert(this.testmsg); // Here it is 'Hi!'

    var elements = $$('img');

    elements.each(function(element) {
      alert(this.testmsg); // Here it is 'undefined', even though I bind 'this'
    }).bind(this);

  }
});
```

I might be doing something horribly wrong, but I can not just figure out what that is.

How can I access 'testmsg' within the each - while using 'Class.create'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XD... small (but important) mistake.

```
elements.each(function(element) {
      alert(this.testmsg); // Here it is 'undefined', even though I bind 'this'
    }.bind(this));
```

you must bind the inside function, not the each function

Good Luck

Comment: Haha, thanks! This is the answer I was looking for showing me what I did 'Horribly wrong'.

Answer (score 1):

this is because this referrs in your case to the element in the each loop.

you can resolve that problem by changing your class a bit (not-tested):

```
MyClass = function(){
    var that = this;
    this.testmsg = 'Hi!';
    alert(this.testmsg); // Here it is 'Hi!'

    elements.each(function(element) {
      alert(that.testmsg); // Here it is 'Hi!'
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this by creating a variable `self` which refers to `this` in the top of your `initialize` function.

```
MyClass = Class.create({
    initialize : function(options) {
        var self = this; // Create a reference to 'this'

        this.testmsg = 'Hi!';

        elements.each(function(element) {
            alert(self.testmsg);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `this` in the closure points to the function's this which I believe is jquery object.

Solution is to store `this` in a `var`:

```
MyClass = Class.create({

  initialize : function(options) {

    this.testmsg = 'Hi!';
    var that = this;
    alert(this.testmsg); // Here it is 'Hi!'

    var elements = $$('img');

    elements.each(function(element) {
      alert(that.testmsg); // Here it is 'undefined', even though I bind 'this'
    }).bind(that);

  }
});
```

Comment: I am using Prototype, not jQuery ;) I am also interested in how I can access testmsg in the closure..